# Why in this code the buffer is flushed when there isn't any newline printed?

Tags: c, windows, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <windows.h>

void p(int n) {

    if (n == 0) return;

    p(n/10);

    if (n%10 < 5) {printf("%d",n%10); Sleep(1000);}

}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",INT_MAX-1);

    p(INT_MAX - 1);

    return 0;
}
```

It should print everything at once because the stream is buffered but it prints the digits separately. I am using gcc under windows.

Comment: Because the buffer is flushed once it fills up? That's how buffered output works.

Comment: Do you understand the code? The buffer isn't filled. printf prints every digit separately instead of printing all them at once and this is the problem. The stream is buffered so this should not happen. And I don't know what is the error here.

Comment: And the actual code you try to run is the exact copy of the code you show here? You don't print a trailing (or a *shudder* leading) newline in your actual code?

Comment: By the way, doing a couple of hundred million recursive calls can't be good for the stack, are you sure you don't get a stack overflow and go into undefined behavior territory?

Comment: Yes, this is the exact code I compile and run. This is a simple recursive function that prints the digits contained in a number that are greater than 5, recursively. There are n recursive calls where n is the length of the number. The recursion is not the problem.

Comment: If the other programs shown here on SO are anything to go by, the C runtime library on Windows doesn't behave the same as on Unix and does output data is if the stream is unbuffered.  I've not got a machine to test on (thank goodness), but we often see Windows programs without newlines at the end of the printing, and the OPs seem to be happy with it.  Each to their own, I guess.

Comment: Missing newline does not mean that the buffer can't be flushed. If your system decides that there are pending chars for too long time or that he simply wants to flush it can.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Ok, once again, let me explain what the code does. I constantly divide the argument of the function by 10. That means that I remove the last digit of that number. INT_MAX-1 has 10 digits and that means that the function is called 10 times. Then i print the digits starting from the first one in the number that is smaller than 5.

Comment: It'd help to include the exact compiler and version you are using. And your program could be simplified to just have a loop in `main` that outputs and sleeps.

Comment: mingw32-gcc-4.7.1, Windows 7

Answer (score 4):

In C there are three possible buffering states for streams:

- `_IONBF` - unbuffered; characters should appear ASAP
- `_IOLBF` - line buffered; characters should appear after a newline
- `_IOFBF` - fully buffered; characters should not appear until stream flushed

Regarding the initial state of `stdout`, C11 7.21.3/7 has to say:

> As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

Since the stream *is* an interactive device in your case, they *must not* be fully buffered. Therefore, `stdout` may either be line buffered or unbuffered. I don't see any other text narrowing this down further.

Apparently on your system, it starts out in unbuffered mode.

You may set line buffering with:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 1024);
```

(I'm not exactly sure what you're supposed to put for the last argument but I think this means that it should use a 1024-byte buffer for the line; flushing if that limit is hit).

However when I tried this on MinGW-w64 4.9.2,  the line-buffering appeared to behave the same as fully-buffered.

I'd speculate that the reason is because this implementation redirects functionality to the MSVC runtime library as much as possible, and perhaps the MSVC runtime doesn't support line-buffering. Which would explain why gcc decides to default to unbuffered, as that is better for interactive programs than fully-buffered.

Comment: "_IOLBF
    For some systems, this provides line buffering. However, for Win32, the behavior is the same as _IOFBF - Full Buffering." ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86cebhfs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Heh. "some systems" meaning "conforming systems"

Comment: Conforming to the standard?

Comment: Can you explain more this sentence(I don't fully understand it): "redirects functionality to the MSVC runtime library as much as possible". And what is MSVC runtime library?

Comment: @J.M MinGW means "minimalist GNU for Windows". It attempts to avoid reimplementing the C specification as much as possible, instead calling functions inside MSVCRTxx.DLL which Windows systems already have.

Comment: I knew that about MinGW and that it's a port of the GNU Compiler Colection but thanks a lot for the last part of the comment, now it's much more clear. edit: What exactly is MSVC and where can I learn about all of this because obviously there is a lot to learn about this mess?

Comment: The `msvcrt.dll` runtime is the C runtime library used by Windows itself.  Third party developers are not supposed to use it, but MinGW ignores that rule.  The Visual Studio runtimes don't do line buffering either, as it happens, but that doesn't violate C11 for the simple reason that Visual Studio doesn't support C11 in the first place. :-)

Answer (score 0):

On gcc under linux, this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void p(int n){
    if (n == 0) return;

    p(n/10);

    printf("%d",n);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",INT_MAX-1);

    p(INT_MAX - 1);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Gives this output:

```
2147483646                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
2212142147214742147482147483214748362147483642147483646
```

Or with a space for clarity:

```
 2 21 214 2147 21474 214748 2147483 21474836 214748364 2147483646
```

I've taken off your n%10 thing for clarity (and because I don't really understand why it's there).

Clearly this is not flushed on my system and I would guess it must therefore be something funky Windows itself is doing. Your code is fine though.

Comment: How do you know it's not flushed? That's why i put Sleep() in my code. Is there a chance for stdout to be unbuffered on windows by default?

Comment: I put sleep in and it just waits 10 seconds before printing the entire block at once.

Comment: It's probably unbuffered by default on windows. I tried switching to buffered and got the same result as you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following test program on Linux:
    #include

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Pre\n");
    printf("Hello world");
    fprintf(stderr, "Post\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Yields the following output when run:

```
Pre<newline>
Post<newline>
Hello world<no newline>
```

Given the [line buffered] stdout comes out after both [unbuffered] stderr, implies that the buffer is flushed either with an atexit handler or when the program terminates and libc gets dereferenced.  Running strace and ltrace indicate the first case doesn't occur, so the output is probably flushed on exit.

I suspect at this level, the behavior is consistent for Windows and Linux.  If it was pointing to a file not stdout, it would be very bad form for the stdio subsystem to allow corruption of a file (missing data) if you forgot to close it.