# What does this sentence says?

Tags: c, operating-system

I've been told this sentence:

> The image rundown flushes buffers before closing file descriptors. This includes stdout

and I don't understand it at all. Can someone explain it well?

Comment: What?   Without the context that you already have because you have all the rest of the docs?

Comment: I read this as "<something> ensures that all data is written to the files before they are closed".  Sounds like a reasonable action, not that I know what this <something> is.

Comment: perhaps this is helps. [printf-flush-at-program-exit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230411/printf-flush-at-program-exit)

Comment: I got it as an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095451/why-in-this-code-the-buffer-is-flushed-when-there-isnt-any-newline-printed/33098288#33098288

Answer (score 2):

if you use the function fclose to close some FILE* variable, it will flush before closing

Example:

```
FILE *fd;
fd = fopen( "file", "w" );
fprintf( fd, "some text" );

/* at this point the file might still be empty */

fclose( fd );

/* now the information is surely written to the file */
```

Answer (score 1):

The image rundown is related to Operating System concepts( [see this](https://books.google.it/books?id=FSX5qUthRL8C&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=image%20rundown%20operating%20system&source=bl&ots=CHavs6H1X_&sig=JlkGuRQWtOLh_5SNDEpSC0zCVuQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBWoVChMI3ffywbO_yAIVYilyCh38mgRL#v=onepage&q=image%20rundown%20operating%20system&f=false) and Par. 4.9.3.1 Performing Image Rundown of [HP OpenVMS Programming Concepts Manual](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/82final/5841/5841pro_016.html)).
This operation flushes(empties, write to file) buffers before close the file descriptors.